# How to build GAS assembly with Android AOSP?

Tags: assembly, arm, android-source, disassembly, neon

I'm trying to build the [Ne10 Library](https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10) into an AOSP app (Android 9). Whilst I have successfully built the C intrinsics functions I am struggling to get the corresponding assembly functions to work. If I add any of the .s files into the blueprint file as a src I get some nasty looking errors like the following:

```
<instantiation>:29:9: error: invalid instruction, did you mean: add, faddd, fadds, qadd, vadd?  
       fadd v20.4s, v0.4s, v16.4s
```

and

```
<instantiation>:38:14: error: register expected  
       ld2 {v0.4s, v1.4s}, [x14], x9
```

Being very new to assembly, I am aware there is a difference in syntax between GAS (as delivered in the Ne10 project) and that which can be build using clang/LLVM but I'm struggling to find the missing pieces of the puzzle online. The errors indicate a bigger problem than just syntax.

Solutions tried:

(1) The Ne10 project features a [script](https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10/blob/master/tools/gas2ios_convert.py) which converts GAS assembly into something that can be interpreted by LLVM. Whilst this does alter the syntax somewhat I'm still getting errors such as:

```
<instantiation>:42:14: error: register expected  
       ld2 {v8.4s, v9.4s}, [x13], x10
```

(2) I've built the Ne10 project using the Android NDK toolchain (android-ndk-r17c) with CMake and tried to dis-assemble the resultant .o files using llvm-objdump (providing my target cpu) with no luck, e.g.

```
error: vector register expected vst1.32 {d22, d23}, [r7]!
```

Perhaps there is a specific set of flags which I'm not using correctly? Is this task even possible?

Comment: This smells a lot like you are trying to assemble 64 bit code for 32 bit or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - hm, perhaps I need a closer look at the Ne10 library, the target is certainly 64 bit.

Comment: Checking some random source files in the Ne10 library you linked, it is all 32 bit ARM code.  The tell-tale sign is that 32 bit ARM has `r0--r15` whereas 64 bit ARM has `w0--w30` resp. `x0--x30`.

Comment: Ne10 definitely not maintained, but one of more recent (2015!) [Android commits](https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10/commit/7fad4fcd2aa43a875b4f61e6d68d4cf6dece83ec) is enabling aarch64, although armv7 is definitely default. Unsure how good aarch64 support is.

Comment: Thanks all - yes, I was mistakenly building for armv7 and having had a closer look at the CMake files the assembly code isn't built for aarch64 :( @fuz feel free to post your comment as an answer.